# update record value based on some other value in the same record

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table in my database:

```
 CREATE TABLE `plans` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `plan` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
      `subscr_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
      `last_payment` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Plan values are `1 MONTH`, `3 MONTHS` and `YEAR` corresponding to 1 month, 3 months and 12 months.

Record example:

```
id----user_id-----plan--------subcr_id-------last_payment--------active

30 |    15     |    1 MONTH  |  A-1   |   2017-05-19 08:22:29   |1
```

I would like to go thorugh every record and update `active` to 0 if `last_payment` happened over a month ago (if the plan for that record is `1M`), over 3 months ago (if the plan for that record is 3 MONTHS`)` and over 12 months ago (if the plan for that record is `YEAR`).

While I am comfortable with simple update statements, this one requires some if logic I don't know how to perform. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update plans set active = case
when plan = '1 MONTH' and last_payment < now() - interval 1 month then 0
when plan = '3 MONTH' and last_payment < now() - interval 3 month then 0
when plan = 'YEAR' and last_payment < now() - interval 1 year then 0
else 1
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like this:

```
UPDATE plans t, (SELECT *  FROM plans) t1
   SET t.active = 0 WHERE date(now()) not between date_add(t1.last_payment,interval t1.plan month)
```

Just need to change the plan field to an integer field, or interval (date), should be easier than making a Case scenario, but you can do it too:

```
UPDATE `plan` SET `active` = CASE
    WHEN plan = '1 MONTH' THEN CAST(not between date_add(last_payment, interval 1 MONTH) AS SIGNED INTEGER);
    WHEN plan = '3 MONTHS' THEN CAST(not between date_add(last_payment, interval 3 MONTH) AS SIGNED INTEGER);
    WHEN plan = '1 YEAR' THEN CAST(not between date_add(last_payment, interval 1 YEAR) AS SIGNED INTEGER);
    ELSE `1`
    END
```

Something like that, hope it helps you